# React vis Line Chart not rendering properly

Tags: reactjs, react-vis

I am using react-vis library for one of my projects. I copied the source code of a sample chart from one of their examples on the site. I copied the example directly but still the chart does not look as expected.

```
import React from 'react';
import {curveCatmullRom} from 'd3-shape';

import {
  XYPlot,
  XAxis,
  YAxis,
  HorizontalGridLines,
  VerticalGridLines,
  LineSeries
} from 'index';

export default function Example(props) {
  return (
    <XYPlot width={300} height={300}>
      <HorizontalGridLines style={{stroke: '#B7E9ED'}} />
      <VerticalGridLines style={{stroke: '#B7E9ED'}} />
      <XAxis
        title="X Axis"
        style={{
          line: {stroke: '#ADDDE1'},
          ticks: {stroke: '#ADDDE1'},
          text: {stroke: 'none', fill: '#6b6b76', fontWeight: 600}
        }}
      />
      <YAxis title="Y Axis" />
      <LineSeries
        className="first-series"
        data={[{x: 1, y: 3}, {x: 2, y: 5}, {x: 3, y: 15}, {x: 4, y: 12}]}
        style={{
          strokeLinejoin: 'round',
          strokeWidth: 4
        }}
      />
      <LineSeries className="second-series" data={null} />
      <LineSeries
        className="third-series"
        curve={'curveMonotoneX'}
        data={[{x: 1, y: 10}, {x: 2, y: 4}, {x: 3, y: 2}, {x: 4, y: 15}]}
        strokeDasharray="7, 3"
      />
      <LineSeries
        className="fourth-series"
        curve={curveCatmullRom.alpha(0.5)}
        data={[{x: 1, y: 7}, {x: 2, y: 11}, {x: 3, y: 9}, {x: 4, y: 2}]}
      />
    </XYPlot>
  );
}
```

[image: Expected]

[image: Actual]

Comment: Are you using the same version?

Comment: yes, I am using the same version

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For this issue, you can import `style.css` from `react-vis` in your component like below,

```
import "react-vis/dist/style.css";
```

Working Code :- https://codesandbox.io/s/musing-yonath-bgg1i?file=/src/App.js

[image]